# I did some work to normalize real estate table but I do not know If it is the correct or not

Tags: database, ms-access

[image]

I created 3 tables from MoonPIS which are Properties,Clint,and Owner as shown in image above

```
FD1: cID          cName
FD2: oID          oName oContact


INSERT INTO Owner ( oID, oName, oContact )
SELECT MoonPIS.oID, MoonPIS.oName, MoonPIS.oContact
FROM MoonPIS;

INSERT INTO Client ( cID, pID, cName )
SELECT MoonPIS.cID, MoonPIS.pID, MoonPIS.cName
FROM MoonPIS;

INSERT INTO Properties ( pID, pAddr, leaseExp, mRent, oID )
SELECT MoonPIS.pID, MoonPIS.pAddr, MoonPIS.leaseExp, MoonPIS.mRent, MoonPIS.oID
FROM MoonPIS;
```

Comment: you want cID in your third insert statement?

Comment: oh yes, I forgot that. Do you think it is good normalization?

Comment: for now, yes, it's fine